# .NET Winforms c# Upload large files

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, upload

I get this error when file length is higher than 18 mb:

> *stream does not support concurrent IO read or write operations*

The error is localized in this section:

```
requestStream.Write(header, 0, header.Length);
if (fileData != null)
{
     // write the file data, if any
     byte[] buffer = new Byte[checked((uint)Math.Min(8192, (int)fileData.Length))];
     int bytesRead;

     try
     {
          while ((bytesRead = fileData.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
          {
               //throws an exception after 3000 loops aprox
               requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
          }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
          string aux = ex.Message;
     }
}

// write footer
requestStream.Write(footer, 0, footer.Length);
return webrequest.GetResponse();
```

I tried with *lock* sentence, `sendChunked = true` and `AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false` But I can't upload files correctly.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, I can find the relationship between ImageList.ImageSize Property and my issue.

Comment: Are you sure that it is possible to upload bigger files then 18 Mb?

Comment: You are uploading to a web server?  The server might just be throwing an odd exception.   Test on a web server you control.

Comment: Maybe the web server sends an error message (read) that the size limit has exceeded while the loop tries to upload (write) data. You can try to check what is sent with between the client and the program with Wireshark or something similar...

Comment: Ok, I'm gonna investigate it

Comment: Exactly! Web server has 120 seconds limit and 10MB max size. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe the web server sends an error message (read) that the size limit has exceeded while the loop tries to upload (write) data to the stream. You can try to check what is sent between the server and the program with Wireshark or some other network sniffer.

Answer (score 0):

Web servers have some limits. You should set these limits so that not exceeded.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).